# Population of div with Textbox, removes the other div from a table cell

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

I am dynamically adding rows/cells in an HTML table. In one such cell, i want to have a text box and some suggestion text just below the text box.
For this I tried following -

```
//Insert a new row at index 1 of an existing HTML table
var row1 = table.insertRow(1);

//insert 2 cells
var cell1 = row1.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row1.insertCell(1);

//Set the HTML for the cells. 2nd one having 2 DIVs
cell1.innerHTML="Label Name: *";
cell2.innerHTML="<div id=\"mytextbox\"/><div id=\"mysuggestiontext\"/>";

var myTextBoxDiv=dojo.byId("mytextbox");
var mySuggestionTextDiv=dojo.byId("mysuggestiontext");

alert("myTextBoxDiv: " + myTextBoxDiv + " mySuggestionTextDiv: " + mySuggestionTextDiv);
//This displays both the elements as HTMLDivElement

//Create a ValidationTextBox and keep at DIV mytextbox
var myValidationTextBox =  new ValidationTextBox(
 { required:true,
   value:"sometext",
   readOnly:false,
 }, "mytextbox");

//Checking the value of the divs again
myTextBoxDiv=dojo.byId("mytextbox");
mySuggestionTextDiv=dojo.byId("mysuggestiontext");

alert("myTextBoxDiv: " + myTextBoxDiv + " mySuggestionTextDiv: " + mySuggestionTextDiv);
//Here 'mySuggestionTextDiv' is displayed as null.
```

Need suggestions on what is wrong with the above code and what is happening to the 2nd DIV 'mysuggestiontext'?
If it is wrong then need some suggestions to accomplish it.

Comment: My guess is you are missing ending **<div>** 's for cell2. It should be `"<div id=\"mytextbox\"></div><div id=\"mysuggestiontext\"></div>"`

Comment: I dont think that's the problem, as its ending in the same tag - <div id=\"mysuggestiontext\"/>

Answer (score 0):

Yet to find the root cause of it. For now I could manage with a workaround by replacing the first div with an input element -

```
cell2.innerHTML="<input type=\"text\" id=\"mytextbox\"/><div id=\"mysuggestiontext\"/>";
```